# Change controls size layout when changing window's size UWP

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, windows-10-universal, uwp-xaml

I would like to make my controls gets bigger with the same margin, It's like giving 10% of the window's size bigger, all controls should be bigger 10% as the window does, they should goes wider if the windows goes too ...etc.

I searched a lot about that and found this topic : https://msdn.microsoft.com/windows/uwp/layout/layouts-with-xaml
but still couldn't know how to make what i want exactly. I don't have many controls they are like 9 only! They are timers, nothing else!

I could do it in Forms or WPF, but in windows UI XAML is blocking so many features, so I can't do it the same way I did for others. That's why I'm trying to find another alternative way to do it.

My Windows Main window WPF (Screenshot):
[image]

WPF XAML :

```
<Page
x:Class="SpecCountdown.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:SpecCountdown"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<Grid x:FieldModifier="public" x:Name="mainGrid" Background="Black" Loaded="Grid_Loaded" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="1910">

    <TextBlock x:FieldModifier="public" x:Name="playerTxt" Margin="57,66,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="PLAYER:" Foreground="#FF0015FF" FontSize="36" Height="56" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="148"/>
    <Border x:FieldModifier="public" x:Name="separator1" Height="1" Margin="43,135,0,0" Background="#8800A8FF" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="552" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
    <TextBlock x:FieldModifier="public" x:Name="modeTxt" Margin="57,149,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="PREP TIME:" Foreground="#FF0015FF" FontSize="42" Height="51" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="247"/>
    <Border x:FieldModifier="public" x:Name="separator2" Height="1" Margin="43,216,0,0" Background="#8800A8FF" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="552" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <TextBlock x:FieldModifier="public" x:Name="nextUpTxt" Margin="57,230,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="NEXT UP:" Foreground="#FF0015FF" FontSize="36" Height="67" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="171"/>
    <TextBlock x:FieldModifier="public" x:Name="currPlayerTxt" Margin="0,66,1333,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="N/A" Foreground="#FF0015FF" FontSize="38" TextAlignment="Right" Height="56" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="349"/>
    <TextBlock x:FieldModifier="public" x:Name="nextPlayerTxt" Margin="228,230,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="N/A" Foreground="#FF0015FF" FontSize="38" Height="56" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="349" TextAlignment="Right"/>
    <TextBlock x:FieldModifier="public" x:Name="timerTxt" Margin="349,153,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="0000:00" Foreground="#FF0015FF" FontSize="38" Height="56" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="228" TextAlignment="Right"/>
</Grid>
```

All what I want to make it flexible as well as I change my window's size.

Comment: Try use the `AdaptiveTrigger `

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that you want to change your controls sizes when the windows sieze change.But the TextBlock's sizes is same as TextBlock's FontSize.For the reason,I use ViewBox that sizes will be same as the Page size.And if you not set the page in Frame,the Page's sizes will as bigger as the windows's sizes.

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
 <Viewbox>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground"
                      Value="#FF0015FF"></Setter>
                    <Setter Property="FontSize"
                      Value="36"></Setter>
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment"
                      Value="Center"></Setter>
                    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment"
                      Value="Center"></Setter>
                    <Setter Property="Margin"
                            Value="10,10,10,10"></Setter>
                </Style>
            </Grid.Resources>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Text="PLAYER:" 
                       ></TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" 
                       Text="N/A"></TextBlock>
            </Grid>
            <Grid Grid.Row="1">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Text="PREP TIME:"></TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1"
                       Text="0000:00"></TextBlock>
            </Grid>
            <Grid Grid.Row="2">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Text="NEXT UP:" ></TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1"
                       Text="N/A"></TextBlock>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </Viewbox>
</Grid>
```

http://7xqpl8.com1.z0.glb.clouddn.com/ChangeControlsSizeLayout.gif

Comment: @GameHackerPM this is a great answer if you're not looking to adapt for different devices and you're only looking to have your application run on a desktop which supports resizing in this manner.

I'd recommend also taking a look at the AdaptiveTrigger which you can use in your XAML to manipulate content when the screen reaches certain sizes. See here for more info: (https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/developers/articles/week03aug15/designing-with-adaptive-triggers-for-windows-10/).

Comment: Best answer ever, thank you very much for this great answer. <3 :)